# how do you import markdown into HTML

Tags: markdown

I want to import markdown "code" into HTML
I was looking around the internet to see if there was a way (other than converting it into HTML or CSS)

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. You might want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If you'd want to insert the *raw* markdown code into your documents, you can wrap it in `<pre> ... </pre>` tags to preserve the whitespaces and then into `<code></code>` tags to render it with a monospaced font. You can further style your document with syntax highlighters such as [Prism](https://prismjs.com/) or [HighlightJS](https://highlightjs.org/).

In case you'd want to convert your markdown to HTML, there are several tools both online and offline, such as [markdown to html](https://markdowntohtml.com/)'s website or [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).

Comment: wow, I didn't think anybody would care to help

Comment: I'm so sorry it took so long. It was a rough experience for me too when I asked my first questions and posted my first answers. Was I able to answer your question though? @pawnadona